# Implementing business logic into models

Tags: php, laravel, tdd, domain-driven-design

I'm little confused about how do I implement some business logic inside my domain models.
I'm using php with Laravel framework, but the question is independent of the framework.

I have the following situation:

- When I update a Programme, I should close all Enrollments related to that.
- Generate a new Remark.

My model Programme has many Remarks and Enrollments as following:

```
ProgrammeController extendes Controller {

  public function update($id)
  {
    $programme = Programme::find($id);
    $programme->fill(Input::all());

    $programme->update();

    //Redirects .....
  }
```

}

```
Programme extends Eloquent {

  public function update()
  {
    if(!$this->valid()) 
        return false;

    $this->save();

    //Should close all enrollments
    $this->closeEnrollments($this->enrollments());

    //Should generate a new remark

  }

  private function closeEnrollments($enrollments)
  {
    foreach($enrollments as $enrollment)
    {
        $enrollment->close();
    }
  }

  public function enrollments()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('Enrollment');
  }

  public function remarks()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('Remark');
  }
```

}

```
Enrollment extends Eloquent {

  public function programme()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('Programme');
  }

  public function close()
  {
    //do something
  }
```

}

```
Remark extends Eloquent {

  public function programme()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('Programme');
  }

  public function generate()
  {
    //do something
  }
```

}

My controller calls the function update() in the model Programme.
How could I implement this situation so that my Models can be testable and following the correct patterns? Because I don't know what is the best way to handle it and to call the function generate() in the class Remark and close() in the class Enrollments.

Many thanks!

Comment: $this->closeEnrollments($this->enrollments());

For this line, you're passing a query object. You probably want to pass a collection containing the enrollments..

$this->closeEnrollments($this->enrollments);

Comment: Thanks Shawn for your help.
Ok, in that point I'll change...
but, to call the generate() function of Remark, should I create a new instance inside the Programme (or this is an anti-pattern) ?

sorry for my bad english! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHPUnit you can mock protected methods or create of subclass that would expose private methods like the closeEnrollments() and thus allows you create stubs for testing - see http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/test-doubles.html for more.

However I would suggest you to improve your architecture and look into concepts like TDD, SOLID, Onion Architecture etc. Those are just the core concepts for higher concepts like DDD (and its components like Value object, Entity, Repository, Service and so on). Eg. in your example the class Programme provides persistence, validation, some other business logic and is an aggregate root at the same time. Class that does too much is hard to test. Also such class is hard to change in future when business requirements change and so on.

Comment: Thanks a million Tomas for your help! I'll have a look at the concepts you suggest and maybe think about improve my architecture.